# Strange result with type casting

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

In the following program:

```
int main(){

    int i = 0x52554153;
    const char *s = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i);
    std::string *s1 = new std::string(s);
    std::cout<<"word is "<<*s1<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am converting 4 byte int into 4 byte "const char" string. The integer value, I have used,is nothing but set of ascii values for character string "RUAS". I am expecting same result in "cout" statement. But it prints "SAUR", which is exact reverse of what I provide.
please explain me the output.

Comment: The byte order of your processor is Little Endian. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 7):

It's called [little-endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little-endian) - most processor architectures store integer values with the *least significant byte first*. By the way, the `string` constructor must receive a null-terminated character array (so it's pure luck that the byte next to your int happened to contain zero).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is *endianness* - on your machine the number is stored with bytes stored in reverse order `0x53415552`.

Also you pass address of an integer variable into `std::string` constructor - that's undefined behavior because that variable constitutes a block of bytes that is not null-terminated and `std::string` constructor accepts null-terminated string only.